# Fanatic badge being awarded to users with no activity

Tags: discussion, feature-request

So I just got my "Fanatic" badge (yay), and I was looking at who else has this badge and I see there are a number of users who have this but only have 101 points which means that they registered coming from another SE site, but haven't actually contributed anything.  Some of them seem to have this badge for a number of sites which makes me suspect they have some automated tool hitting the site once a day to gain this gold badge.

May I suggest that this badge only be issued to user who meet some activity criteria, like having at least 500 reputation points?

Answer (score 3):

You don't actually have to do anything when you visit - just do more than visit the home page.

It would be good if you edited, voted, posted, etc. but it's not essential.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to me that you get the same level of badge for editing 500 posts as you do for opening the homepage once a day..

Comment: @Steven - you have to more than open the homepage though. And given the at the SE "day" is UTC based it can be tricky :)